# How to lazy load module after api response in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular8, angular-routing

I want to lazy load a module after API response

below are my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'student', loadChildren: () => import('./student.module').then(m => m.StudentModule) },
  { path: 'school', loadChildren: () => import('./school.module').then(m => m.SchoolModule) },
  { path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];
```

What I want is something like Facebook doing for profile handling for example

facebook.com/ABCD is my profile **(A Different Module)**

facebook.com/EFGH is my page **(Another Different Module)**

In angular, I want something like when I access a URL like **site.com/abcd** it will first check if route param **abcd** is a user profile or an institution page and then based on the response it will lazy load the student or school module

I have a couple of ideas for this like make a common component and then in that component make API calls and check if route param is student profile or school profile then load their components accordingly something like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: LandingComponent },
  { path: ':profile_token', component : CommonComponent },
  { path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];
```

then in CommonComponent

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isProfileRoute">
         <app-user-profile></app-user-profile>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="isSchoolRoute">
         <app-school-profile></app-school-profile>
</ng-container>
```

But here in the method as you can see both components are loading and I feel its not a good way to handle it 
so if is there any way to lazy load a whole module containing routes and components based on API call it will be really great and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe dynamic loading in the routing could help you?

app-routing.module.ts:

```
           {
                path: ':profile_token',
                loadChildren: async () => {
                    const service = AppInjector.get(YourService);
                    if (service.isStudent()) {
                        const a = await import('./modules/student/student.module');
                        return a['StudentModule'];
                    }
                    const b = await import('./modules/school/school.module');
                    return b['SchoolModule'];
                }
            }
```

And in the AppRoutingModule:

```
export class AppRoutingModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        AppInjector = this.injector;
    }
}
```

And before the routes array:

```
export let AppInjector: Injector;
```

Comment: will it block the thread ? i don't know but if api takes longer time i don't want browser to say  ""site.com is not responding  Terminate or wait ?""  but i will give it a shot

Comment: How should it block? Its async.

Comment: await is been used here that's why i said does it block the thread or not.

Comment: The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can be used inside an Async block only. The keyword Await makes JavaScript wait until the promise returns a result. It has to be noted that it only makes the async function block wait and not the whole program execution

Comment: in my service i am awaiting for route.params but promise never finises i am stuck here

Comment: Ok we cannot access the route.param untill our current await finises so i used window.location.pathname instead  to get the current url  now i am going to test Server sided rendering i will mark it solved once it works on server side as well

Comment: Works perfectly in development mode but when i run it on server side it throws error and server did not respond until time out 

error is ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Sounds like your JSON has references on itself so its an endless loop and can't be parsed?

Comment: but in development mode it was parsing without any error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling app-user-profile and app-school-profile in your common component. If you want Angular to lazy load your module as soon as the route is called you have to use the Angular Router (https://angular.io/guide/router).

You have to specify a  where the router should create the content.
In your common component you have to create a router redirect to either the profile or the school route:

```
this.router.navigate(['either the url of profile or the url of school']);
```

Comment: if i wanted to do that i would have directly used site.com/student/abcd or site.com/school/abcd but what i want is to load corresponding component without redirecting  in a efficient way

Comment: so if you navigate to lazzy loaded module after api call as suggested above in the answer, it will automatically load the component too, isn't it?

Comment: Correctly. That is described in this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules